# Python input is not working properly when used within an if statement

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

I made a quick budgeting program to determine how long it would take to buy something, and I ran into a problem. Whenever I try and run it, the one-time sales items don't get added to the balance. My code is as follows:

```
graphicsCard = 50
amdCpu = 80
itelCpu = 99
ram = 140
guitar = 199
case = 99
balance = 21
if (input('Has the graphics card been sold yet?').lower == "yes"):
    balance += graphicsCard
if (input('Has the AMD cpu been sold yet?').lower == "yes"):
    balance += amdCpu
if (input('Has the intel CPU been sold yet?').lower == "yes"):
    balance += intelCpu
if (input('Has the RAM been sold yet?').lower == "yes"):
    balance += ram
if (input('Has the Guitar been sold yet?').lower == "yes"):
    balance += guitar
if (input('Has the Case been sold yet?').lower == "yes"):
    balance += case
```

I added an else statement to after the first if, to detect if it was reading my 'yes' answer properly, and it was not.

Comment: You've forgotten to call the `lower` method, with `()`. So, instead of testing whether the result of calling `lower()` on the input string matches `"yes"`, you're testing whether the `lower` method itself matches `"yes"`. Which of course it doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

`lower` is a method, you need to *call* it:

```
if input('Has the graphics card been sold yet?').lower() == "yes":
```

Note, as I show you don't need parentheses around the condition itself.

Answer (score 1):

You should try .lower()

```
>>> myinput = input('Enter something: ')
Enter something: yes
>>> myinput.lower
<built-in method lower of str object at 0x7f79b2391068>
>>> myinput.lower()
'yes'
```